# Facing `html` cleaning challenge using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting `dusty` html from back-end. (back-end converts the .doc to html)i would like to clear the tags. i used a each iterator, but i am not get the out put as like the expectation.

1) I am not able to put `space` between words (span has space in between)

2) I don't know to wrap the content in single `strong` element in case if this required

here is my html :

```
<p style="margin-right:0pt;margin-left:47.55pt;margin-bottom:0pt;line-height:normal;font-size:11pt;"> 
  <strong>
    <span style="font-family:Arial;">OUT</span>
  </strong>
  <strong>
   <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;">D</span>
 </strong>
 <strong>
   <span style="font-family:Arial;">OOR</span>
 </strong>
 <strong>
   <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.5pt;"> </span>
 </strong>
 <strong>
   <span style="font-family:Arial;">COOLING</span>
 </strong>
 <strong>
   <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.45pt;"> </span>
 </strong>
 <strong>
   <span style="font-family:Arial;">OF</span>
 </strong>
 <strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.15pt;"> </span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">AL</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.15pt;"> </span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">GH</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;">A</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">RAFFA</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.6pt;"> </span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;">SP</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">ORTS</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.4pt;"> </span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">CL</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;">U</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">B</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.3pt;"> </span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">FOR</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.2pt;"> </span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">AS</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;">P</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">IRE</span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:-0.4pt;"> </span>
</strong>
<strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial;">ZONE</span>
</strong> 

</p>
```

My try :

```
$('p').children('strong').find('span').each(function () {
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

Note: I have no.of `paragraphs` in each pages.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdxvx1qp/)

**UPDATE:**

Nearly i am expecting this output:

```
<p style="font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;"><strong>OUTDOOR COOLING OF AL GHARAFFA SPORTS CLUB FOR ASPIRE ZONE</strong></p>
```

Comment: Give an example of how you would like this content to show..

Comment: Try this http://demo.chobits.ch/css3/bottom-input/ . There is a function to remove all HTML tags and leave only TextNodes. You may modify it for your situation.

Comment: what about if use `replace` function

Comment: How about this:  http://jsfiddle.net/qdxvx1qp/4/

Comment: @RadekPech - how can i use for my requirement? my requirement is un-uniformed

Comment: @aroth, it is working, but the elements text alignment missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this really easily using the .text() of all the spans:

```
$("span").text()
```

will give you

```
OUTDOOR COOLING OF AL GHARAFFA SPORTS CLUB FOR ASPIRE ZONE
```

So you can wrap this up in `<p>` and `<strong>` as a one-liner:

```
$("<p style='font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;'><strong>" + $("span").text() + "</p></strong>");
```

which you could use like this:

```
$("#output").prepend(...the above...)
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/vh8ehn0u/1/

And to make it work for multiple paras, do this:

```
$("p").each(function(idx, para) {
        var output = $("<p style='font-family:Arial;letter-spacing:0.05pt;'><strong>" + $("span", $(para)).text() + "</p></strong>");
        // Do something with output here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inline styles, and you don't need `<strong>` tags - use CSS for that -

Suddenly, this becomes much easier & cleaner.

```
$("strong span").each(function(){ 
    $("body,#orNewParentElementOfYourChoice").append("<p>"+$(this).text()+"</p>"); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify you HTML structure of the page, but if you don't want to do so, then [Here is the working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfpc4wwb/) for you.

I have deleted all but one of the `<strong>` tags here, and put the desired output in the `<span>` inside that remaining `<strong>` element.